# Existing library to calculate code complexity of a block of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-analysis, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm given a string which contains an arbitrary amount of code.  I want to calculate a number which represents the code complexity of that string.  Something like:

```
int complexity = Lib.FindComplexity(someString);
```

I realize there are a lot of tools out there that will do this for you.  **These tools will not work for me, because I want to do it programmatically.**  I'd love for the library to be in C#, but will work with anything at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find something ?? for your question @joeB

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using one of those existing tools and wrapping it in a library?  For instance, you might be able to use the NDepend.Console.exe by calling it from your code with the parameters you want, and parse out the result.

Answer (score 1):

NDepend is a great tool, although not cheap at the time I looked at it. If money isn't an option, I'd look into using reflection and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity. It doesn't meet your requirement with any string but you could definitely test assemblies you created.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reflector and the code metrics plug-in available for it.

Answer (score 0):

A library such as this must be able to *parse an arbitrary language
fragment*, and then compute the complexity metrics over the parsed fragment.
Most metrics tools have at best a parser for the entire language,
not just a fragment, so you are likely to be hard pressed to find
many solutions.

There is one system that can provide you what you need:
our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.  It provides parsers
for many languages (such as Java and C#;
it is unclear what language you want to analyze).
DMS has been used already to implement these kinds of metrics
for several langauges (Java, C#, JavaScript, COBOL)
and the process of doing this is straigtforward.
And *DMS does parse langauge fragments*, and amazingly,
the metrics implementation actually operate on such fragments.
You could customize DMS to implement exactly what you want.
See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html
and for derived metrics tools, 
http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Metrics/index.html